# Using html and css in an asp.net mvc application

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have recently started learning asp.net mvc. I'm not sure how to frame this, but is the html/css development different for asp webforms and mvc (Can i use the same code as in an asp.net application's .aspx file in a corresponding mvc application's .cshtml file)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the code and the way it works is different. For example, in Webforms you add textboxes with a distinct ID which you can call from your call behind, for example:

```
txt_Name.Text
```

In MVC you have to get your data from a bound model or view model and add the components via different tags you add in your HTML. This means you get your data from an object and you have to save the data in your controller 'manually'. In MVC you can´t access the properties of an input like you would do in a Webforms application.

As per using headers, labels, etc. you can use them but more like in a templating engine like Twig, not using components from the toolbox like in Webforms.

The css would work more like in static html or when you use the CSSClass property of the Webforms component.

Hope to have answered your question.

Comment: Thank you! What is the documentation related to this. For eg., the html tutorials on w3 schools cannot be used for mvc, right?

Comment: @rahulSaha HTML is still HTML.

Comment: @rahulSaha Yes, any HTML tutorial you can find on the web will work in MVC. Actually I think is a lot easier implementing some CSS and Javascript stuff in MVC then in ASP.NET Webforms.